# Arduino code has too much duplicating code

Tags: arduino, serial-port, rgb

Im having an issue making a mastermind game on Arduino.
I have 4 rgb leds that each have names for their pins (red1, green1, blue1, red2, green2, blue2, etc.)

Now my issue is when I entered 4 colors to compare to the colors that the Arduino chose in the beginning of the game. The code is too repetitive, and since Im still learning Arduino I was wondering if there is a solution to this.

Here is the part of my code that assignes colors to the leds with the chosen color (colorcode 1 = green, 2 = red, etc.)

```
    void Convertmycolor()
{
  if (colorpicker1 == 1)
  {
    red1 = 0;
    green1 = 255;
    blue1 = 255;

  }
  else if (colorpicker1 == 2)
  {

    red1 = 0;
    green1 = 0;
    blue1 = 255;
  }
  else if (colorpicker1 == 3)
  {

    red1 = 255;
    green1 = 255;
    blue1 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker1 == 4)
  {
    red1 = 255;
    green1 = 0;
    blue1 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker1 == 5)
  {

    red1 = 255;
    green1 = 255;
    blue1 = 255;
  }










  if (colorpicker2 == 1)
  {
    red2 = 0;
    green2 = 255;
    blue2 = 255;

  }
  else if (colorpicker2 == 2)
  {

    red2 = 0;
    green2 = 0;
    blue2 = 255;
  }
  else if (colorpicker2 == 3)
  {

    red2 = 255;
    green2 = 255;
    blue2 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker2 == 4)
  {
    red2 = 255;
    green2 = 0;
    blue2 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker2 == 5)
  {

    red2 = 255;
    green2 = 255;
    blue2 = 255;
  }











  if (colorpicker3 == 1)
  {
    red3 = 0;
    green3 = 255;
    blue3 = 255;

  }
  else if (colorpicker3 == 2)
  {

    red3 = 0;
    green3 = 0;
    blue3 = 255;
  }
  else if (colorpicker3 == 3)
  {

    red3 = 255;
    green3 = 255;
    blue3 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker3 == 4)
  {
    red3 = 255;
    green3 = 0;
    blue3 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker3 == 5)
  {

    red3 = 255;
    green3 = 255;
    blue3 = 255;
  }








  if (colorpicker4 == 1)
  {
    red4 = 0;
    green4 = 255;
    blue4 = 255;

  }
  else if (colorpicker4 == 2)
  {

    red4 = 0;
    green4 = 0;
    blue4 = 255;
  }
  else if (colorpicker4 == 3)
  {

    red4 = 255;
    green4 = 255;
    blue4 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker4 == 4)
  {
    red4 = 255;
    green4 = 0;
    blue4 = 0;
  }
  else if (colorpicker4 == 5)
  {

    red4 = 255;
    green4 = 255;
    blue4 = 255;
  }
}
```

As you can see its very repetitive and I want it to be shorter. I tried googling but didnt see anything that could help me in this situation (or im bad at searching)

Hopefully you can help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: Look for https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/ and write a function to set the colors https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FunctionDeclaration

Answer (score 1):

You can use array index to map your values eg like this :

```cpp
#define COLOR_LENGTH 4
#define PICKER_LENGTH 4

struct Color {
    uint8_t r, g, b;
};

const Color colorTable[] = {
    {0, 255, 255},
    {0, 0, 255},
    {255, 255, 0},
    {255, 0, 0},
    {255, 255, 255}
};

uint8_t colorPickers[PICKER_LENGTH];
Color colors[COLOR_LENGTH];
```

And converting is just mapping the colors to the right index :

```cpp
//set the pickers
colorPickers[0] = 3;
colorPickers[1] = 1;
colorPickers[2] = 4;
colorPickers[3] = 5;
//set colors according to table
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < COLOR_LENGTH; i++) {
    colors[i] = colorTable[colorPickers[i] - 1];
}
```